# mysql query performance SUM, group by date

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, sum

I have this query below in a mysql database.  The query is taking ~6 seconds to run on ~1-2 million rows.  I have indexs on date, uniqueuserid, collectiontype.

How can I increase the performance of this query in mysql?

```
select 
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(collection.date),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') as date, 
COUNT(distinct collection.uniqueuserid) as convertingusers, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 then valueofitem end) as valueofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 then 1 end) as numofitems, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 and collection.network = 1 then collection.valueofitem end) as col1valueofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 and collection.network = 1 then 1 end) as col1numofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 and collection.network = 2 then collection.valueofitem end) as col2valueofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 and collection.network = 2 then 1 end) as col2numofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 and collection.network = 3 then collection.valueofitem end) as col3valueofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 1 and collection.network = 3 then 1 end) as col3numofitem, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 2 then collection.valueofitem end) as collectiontypeB, 
SUM(case when collection.type = 3 then collection.valueofitem end) as collectiontypeC,
COUNT(distinct collection.uniqueuserid) as convertingusers 

from collection
where collection.date > date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 3 WEEK) 
group by DATE_FORMAT(collection.date,'%Y-%m-%d') order by collection.date DESC limit 500
```

As requested, I've run an analysis with "EXPLAIN" before the query

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     ALL                 1196352 Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED collection  ALL                 1196352
```

Comment: Put an `EXPLAIN` in front of that query and run it.  Then update your answer with the output of that query.

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts:

1. You are grouping by `DATE_FORMAT(collection.date,'%Y-%m-%d')` yet you're selecting time (`DATE_FORMAT(MIN(collection.date),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')`)
2. If `collection.date` is a `datetime` field, then `GROUP BY DATE(collection.date)` and do the formatting in the `SELECT`.

I would recommend putting the `CASE`s inside a subquery, then performing the rollup like so (you'll need to add the column alias's):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') AS date,
    COUNT(a.uniqueuserid) AS convertingusers, 
    SUM(a.valueofitem),
    SUM(a.numofitems),
    SUM(a.col1valueofitem),
    SUM(a.col1numofitem),
    SUM(a.col2valueofitem),
    SUM(a.col2numofitem),
    SUM(a.col3valueofitem),
    SUM(a.col3numofitem),
    SUM(a.collectiontypeB)
FROM
    (SELECT collection.date AS date,
        collection.uniqueuserid AS convertingusers,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1
            THEN valueofitem
        END AS valueofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1
            THEN 1
        END AS numofitems,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1 AND collection.network = 1 
            THEN collection.valueofitem
        END AS col1valueofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1 AND collection.network = 1
            THEN 1
        END AS col1numofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1 AND collection.network = 2
            THEN collection.valueofitem
        END AS col2valueofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1 AND collection.network = 2
            THEN 1
        END AS col2numofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1 AND collection.network = 3
            THEN collection.valueofitem
        END AS col3valueofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 1 AND collection.network = 3
            THEN 1
        END AS col3numofitem,
        CASE
        WHEN collection.type = 2
            THEN collection.valueofitem
        END AS collectiontypeB,
        CASE
            WHEN collection.type = 3
            THEN collection.valueofitem
        END AS collectiontypeC
    FROM collection
    WHERE collection.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 WEEK)) a
GROUP BY DATE(a.date)
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 500
```

Comment: Thanks.  The date() function makes a lot of sense.  I put that in but don't see much improvement.  I also made the subquery as you recommended and I'm not seeing a big performance bump there.  Are case functions particularly slow? Is there a better way to do this other than case functions?

Comment: @Jeremy Would you be able to edit your question with the `EXPLAIN` output?